# Reactions inside the class

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I'd like `mobx` to trigger a reaction whenever an observable changes. I want it to be trigerred inside the class that has that observable so the trigger method could manipulate other data in the store, for example data in a sub-store.

```
class Animal {
    name
    energyLevel

    constructor(name) {
        reaction(
            () => giraffe.isHungry,
            isHungry => {
                if (isHungry) {
                    console.log("Now I'm hungry!")
                } else {
                    console.log("I'm not hungry!")
                }
                console.log("Energy level:", giraffe.energyLevel)
            }
        )
        this.name = name
        this.energyLevel = 100
        makeAutoObservable(this)
    }

    reduceEnergy() {
        this.energyLevel -= 10
    }

    get isHungry() {
        return this.energyLevel < 50
    }
}
```

(The example is taken from the docs: https://mobx.js.org/reactions.html)

If I move the reaction inside the constructor function, it will not be triggered (in the original code it's outside the class). How can I trigger reactions inside the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, to refer to the current instance of the class you need to use `this` keyword, like `this.isHungry` and etc.

And second is that you need to use `reaction` after you use `makeAutoObservable`, so just move it in the end of constructor:

```
class Animal {
  name;
  energyLevel;

  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.energyLevel = 100;
    makeAutoObservable(this);

    reaction(
      () => this.isHungry,
      (isHungry) => {
        if (isHungry) {
          console.log("Now I'm hungry!");
        } else {
          console.log("I'm not hungry!");
        }
        console.log('Energy level:', this.energyLevel);
      }
    );
  }

  reduceEnergy() {
    this.energyLevel -= 60;
  }

  addEnergy() {
    this.energyLevel += 60;
  }

  get isHungry() {
    return this.energyLevel < 50;
  }
}

const animal = new Animal('cat');

animal.reduceEnergy();
animal.addEnergy();
```

[image: Edit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74207374/mobx-reactions-inside-the-class]